# Full name month format in QCalendar sample

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qdate, qcalendarwidget

I need a calendar widget for the app I am writing in PyQt5 and I found this sample source code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QCalendarWidget, QWidget, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Example(QWidget):
   def __init__(self):
      super(Example, self).__init__()
      self.initUI()
   def initUI(self):
      my_calendar = QCalendarWidget(self)
      my_calendar.setGridVisible(True)
      my_calendar.move(10, 20)
      my_calendar.clicked[QDate].connect(self.show_date)
      self.my_label = QLabel(self)
      date = my_calendar.selectedDate()
      self.my_label.setText(date.toString())
      self.my_label.move(10, 220)
      self.setGeometry(100,100,600,270)
      self.setWindowTitle('Calendar')
      self.show()
   def show_date(self, date):
      self.my_label.setText(date.toString())

def main():
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   ex = Example()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

and In the result should be like as this pic as the developer says:

[image: the month format is full name]

but When i run this code in my system i get everything write except month format, how can I have full name month format like  May,June,... and not M01,M02,...
this is result i get when i run the code in my system:

[image]

Comment: Try setting locale `my_calendar.setLocale(QLocale(QLocale.English))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html#toString-1) point out:

> ### QString QDate::toString(Qt::DateFormat format = Qt::TextDate
>
> This is an overloaded function.
>
> Returns the date as a string. The format parameter determines the
> format of the string.
>
> If the format is Qt::TextDate, the string is formatted in the default
> way. QDate::shortDayName() and QDate::shortMonthName() are used to
> generate the string, **so the day and month names will be localized
> names using the system locale, i.e. QLocale::system()**. An example of
> this formatting is "Sat May 20 1995".
>
> If the format is Qt::ISODate, the string format corresponds to the ISO
> 8601 extended specification for representations of dates and times,
> taking the form yyyy-MM-dd, where yyyy is the year, MM is the month of
> the year (between 01 and 12), and dd is the day of the month between
> 01 and 31.
>
> If the format is Qt::SystemLocaleShortDate or
> Qt::SystemLocaleLongDate, the string format depends on the locale
> settings of the system. Identical to calling
> QLocale::system().toString(date, QLocale::ShortFormat) or
> QLocale::system().toString(date, QLocale::LongFormat).
>
> If the format is Qt::DefaultLocaleShortDate or
> Qt::DefaultLocaleLongDate, the string format depends on the default
> application locale. This is the locale set with QLocale::setDefault(),
> or the system locale if no default locale has been set. Identical to
> calling QLocale().toString(date, QLocale::ShortFormat) or
> QLocale().toString(date, QLocale::LongFormat).
>
> If the format is Qt::RFC2822Date, the string is formatted in an RFC
> 2822 compatible way. An example of this formatting is "20 May 1995".
>
> If the date is invalid, an empty string will be returned.
>
> Warning: The Qt::ISODate format is only valid for years in the range 0
> to 9999. This restriction may apply to locale-aware formats as well,
> depending on the locale settings.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

As noted, the formats depend on the QLocale, in your case you probably have a QLocale different from the developer, so there are 2 solutions:

- Set QLocale in the application:

  ```py
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  QLocale.setDefault(QLocale(QLocale.English)) # <---
  # ...
  ```
- Set QLocale in QCalendarWidget:

  ```py
  my_calendar.setLocale(QLocale(QLocale.English))
  ```